Removing leading comments from field data
I am working on building logic to remove the leading comments from field. Requirement is I need to check if first word of string in field  is select% or copy% or with%select% then it's extract else non extract. The issue is in some cases I am getting comments in starting sometimes after newline or can be direct, so I am not able to categorise it correctly.
Example :
\n/*Comment */
/* Comment

*/
Select * from test - it's an extract
\n--comment
 Select * from test - extract

 --comment 
 Select*from test -extract

/* Comment*/

 Select * from test- extract

Example :
Input -



query string
categorization




Select*from abc



--select*from abc



--this is comment



/* This is comment



Select*from cde




Output should be as below currently I am getting non extract if it's coming with comment. I need to remove leading comment blocks only. Comment can be present in one line multiple lines, so different pattern can be with /*** or -- or /* etc.



query string
categorization




Select*from abc
Extract


--select*from abc
Extract


--this is comment



/* This is comment



Select*from cde
Extract



I have tried to check position of comment example, but it's not working as expected.
CASE
WHEN POSITION('/*' IN query string) = 1 
THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(query string FROM POSITION('*/' IN query string) + 2))
WHEN POSITION('--' IN query string) = 1 
THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(normalized_query_string FROM POSITION(' ' IN query string) + 1))
END


Are you really using version 9.4? Please upgrade to a supported version first.

@FrankHeikens-Its dba decision to keep it..they are planning to upgrade it soon but for now it's 9.4

Already 4 years EOL, no support. Maybe it's time to look for a new DBA?
https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Sure Frank,but I am ok if you can please help me with SQL query  on upgraded version..that would be great help

Here's an older thread where someone tried parsing SQL with a SQL regex. Check out the tools at the wiki and how pgpool-II does it.

Hi @Zegarek - I am avoiding regex as we have huge volume of data and regex will be expensive for this case.

My recommendation stands: consider a proper SQL parser for this task. Avoiding LIKE, SIMILAR TO and POSIX regular expressions might be a good idea but it'll definitely make your task harder and affect code quality. There's a point when you'll cease to see any performance benefits of avoiding regex and find yourself trying to navigate a spaghetti code that's slowly becoming just another regex engine, and not necessarily a good one.

If you really want to do it this way, please clarify your rules and provide an MRE. Right now, the examples you provided weren't consistent with the logic you described and the code you showed is incomplete and what's there, isn't syntactically valid. It also doesn't try to classify the examples as Extract or null, instead it's trying to modify the examples.

@zegarek,I am trying to classify the query string into extract and non extract.

@Raj Sure, but that's not what your code attempts to do and the rules that lead to a string being assigned to either class, aren't entirely clear. Take a look at these and add comments how each one should be classified and why.

@Zegarek- https://dbfiddle.uk/g7Opejjy

@Raj You broke that fiddle. It's making it harder to understand if your problem is buried under syntax issues - please try to fix this. Your remark "Extract just need to remove leading comments and check first string" suggests you're trying to both classify them as well as modify them. Edit your question to make that clear, include adequate input example and expected output. I suppose you should now have 3 columns on output: one showing raw input, one showing how it got modified and one that says whether the modified version got classified as Extract.

@zegarek- Requirement is in query string if there is comment before SQL then I don't need to consider that comment I just need to check if SQL starts with  select then it's extract.Comment can be single line or multi line.

@Raj Edit the question to clarify the rules and show them applied to examples. Add an MRE that doesn't throw syntax errors.

Sure @Zegarek-I have added in the question

@Zegarek- please let me know if you need any information.I don't know what exactly need to be done to achieve it.I have tried regex too '^\s*(--[^\n]\n|/\.?\/\s*) but it's not working as well.

@Zegarek-Do you need any other information?
